# Vue.js 2 : Best way to load different elements based on multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an api like so, which each return a list of json objects

```
/api/data/foo
/api/data/bar
/api/data/fizz
```

I also have a single page application with a single table and a drop down selector.

```
<select v-model="tableChoice">
    <option selected>Foo</option>
    <option>Bar</option>
    <option>Fizz</option>
</select>

<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th v-for="header in tableHeaders">
                {{ header }}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="record in tableData" :key="record.recordId">
            <td v-for="element in record">{{element}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Currently I just have 3 seperate Vues like so, each with their own API url and set of table headers.

```
var fooLink = 'api/foo';

new Vue ({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        tableHeaders:["Record ID","Record Name", "Record Detail"],
        tableData: null,
        dataChoice: 'Foo'
    },
    methods:{
        getFooData: function(){
            this.$http.get(fooLink).then(function(response){
                this.tableData = response.data;
            }, function(error){
                console.log(error.statusText);
            });
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.getFooData();
    }
});
```

How can I use a single table or component, and based on the tableChoice variable, determine what API url is used to populate the tables data?

The documentation on components is not clear on conditional loading with props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select v-model="tableChoice">
    <option value="foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    <option value="fizz">Fizz</option>
</select>
```

Use select box change handler.

```
new Vue ({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        tableData: null,
        tableChoice: 'foo'
    },
    computed: {
        apiUrl() {
            switch (this.tableChoice) {
                case 'foo': return '/api/data/foo';
                case 'bar': return '/api/data/bar';
                case 'fizz': return '/api/data/fizz';
            }
        },
        tableHeaders() {
            switch (this.tableChoice) {
                case 'foo': return ['Foo'];
                case 'bar': return ['Bar'];
                case 'fizz': return ['Fizz'];
            }
        },
    },
    watch: {
        tableChoice() {
            this.getFooData();
        },
    },
    methods: {
        getFooData() {
            this.$http.get(this.apiUrl).then(response => {
                this.tableData = response.data;
            }, error => {
                console.log(error.statusText);
            });
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getFooData();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello, this answer works very well. I have a questions, is it better to not use components for operations like this in VueJS?

Comment: You can use components if you want! I prefer to use components if my app becomes larger.

Comment: Ok cool. Thank you. I will avoid components for now. I feel its adding to my confusion getting started with Vue

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
<select v-model="tableChoice">
    <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.apiURL">
        {{ option.text }}
      </option>
</select>

<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th v-for="header in tableHeaders">
                {{ header }}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="record in tableData" :key="record.recordId">
            <td v-for="element in record">{{element}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**script**

```
new Vue ({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        tableHeaders:["Record ID","Record Name", "Record Detail"],
        tableData: null,
        tableChoice: this.options[0].apiURL},// default selected value
        options: [
            {text: 'Foo', apiURL: '/api/data/foo'},
            {text: 'Bar', apiURL: '/api/data/bar'},
            {text: 'Fizz', apiURL: '/api/data/fizz'}
        ]
    },
    methods:{
        getData: function(apiUrl){
            this.tableData = null;
            this.$http.get(apiUrl).then(function(response){
                this.tableData = response.data;
            }, function(error){
                console.log(error.statusText);
            });
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.getData(this.tableChoice);
    },
    watch: {
        tableChoice(newValue){
            this.getData(newValue);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I really like this solution as well. The "watch" directive allows me to change the currently loaded headers and grouping the options in a variable list is more maintainable. Thank you

Comment: @user2120640 happy to help:)